# How do I use a select option twice with AngularJS while an option is still selected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three select options in my code like so:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-change="doSomething()">
    <option value="somevalue">some option</option>
    <option value="someothervalue">some other option</option>
</select>
```

The problem I am experiencing is that after I click on 'some option' and trigger the ng-change for the first time, I then can't select that option again as it won't trigger the ng-change. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: What I hope to do is trigger the ng-change again without having to un-select the option.

Comment: you are not changing the value therefore there is no change. So, I am not getting the issue. It is working as expected

Comment: Yes, but if I click the dropdown again and select the same option I want to get the same result, but nothing will happen. I want to trigger the ng-change again, even if the option is already selected.

Comment: but it is not changing

Comment: Yes, but I still want to trigger the event on the click, but the click is not detected on the option. If I use ng-click, then any time I click the dropdown it will trigger. I want to trigger the event on the option with a click because it is not changing so ng-change will not work.

Comment: I've managed to solve this by creating a variable to take the last value every time the dropdown is clicked. When compared it tells me whether or not to fire the click event.